# joomla custom titles seo

Tags: php, joomla, seo

I am using a plugin called jumi in joomla. It allows me to write custom php code. This php page takes `$_GET['id]` from the url and outputs content. Now I want to have a custom title depending upon the `$_GET['id']`. I set `<title>` tags inside the php code, but that title is not coming as the page title.

Comment: please show some code, which you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This not happen because the include you are doing is in the `<body>` tag. The title have to be in the `<head>` tag. I've been using jumi and I think you cannot achieve your goal in the way you're trying to do it.